# What does this mean? ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

Tags: ssh, arch-linux, sshd, port-forwarding

I am trying to create an SSH fileserver at home which I can access elsewhere. It is currently running Arch linux kernel 4.16.3-1-ARCH.
I can gain access through my other computer via LAN easily:

```
bred@loaf:~$ ssh landau@192.168.0.177 -p 80
landau@192.168.0.177's password:
```

But trying to access via WAN has proven more difficult. I've been trying to use port 80 since port 22 seems to be blocked. And I know 80 is open according to [ismyportopen.com](http://ismyportopen.com). I guess I don't really know what I'm doing and the arch wiki seems to be failing me.

I notice I've gotten this error when trying to connect via WAN while on the same LAN.

```
bred@loaf:~$ ssh landau@65.157.96.234 -vv -p 80
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "65.157.96.234" port 80
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 65.157.96.234 [65.157.96.234] port 80.
debug1: connect to address 65.157.96.234 port 80: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 65.157.96.234 port 80: Connection refused
```

While I get this error while trying to connect through WAN through a computer on the same LAN, but attempting to connect from the same LAN computer (not host) via a VPN.

```
bred@loaf:~$ ssh landau@65.157.96.234 -vv -p 80
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "65.157.96.234" port 80
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 65.157.96.234 [65.157.96.234] port 80.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/bred/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/bred/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/bred/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/bred/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/bred/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/bred/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/bred/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/bred/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Here is a copy of my /etc/ssh/sshd_config on the host, excluding commented lines:

```
AllowUsers landau
Port 80
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/ssh/sftp-server
```

My host's /etc/hosts.allow and /etc/hosts.deny didn't exist by default. I added `sshd:ALL` to the allow file and that didn't seem to help.

Comment: This will be a specific case of the general question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198895/ .